# ASMX file with AutoComplete not working on iis6 windows 2003 virtual server

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, web-services, asmx

I have an asp.net 4.0 AJAX/JQUERY Autocomplete.asmx webservice that works fine on localhost development environment. I have published the website and copied the files to the iis6 windows 2003 virtual server and then it does not work there. I have tried making a separate application under the main website and referencing the service asmx there but that does not work either. The weird thing is that I do not get an error message. I have checked the log files and I can see that the ASMX file was loaded and reference and there is no error logged there either. I am stuck at this moment. I am not sure what else to try to troubleshoot this problem. Any techniques or advice would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried looking to browser console, if there is any internal server error `500` type or something else?

Comment: I just checked pressing F12 browser debug in IE DOM Explorer and it said AutoComplete="off" I have no idea how to switch it to on as by default it should be "on" as far as I know

Comment: That same setting is in my development environment and webservice Autocomplete still works there but still does not work in production environment no matter what. Please advise.

Comment: Just use chrome and then check, it is a better tool to catch such errors.

Comment: I checked and there are absolutely no errors shown. I'm not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: I just tried again and got the following error in Chrome: ../AutoComplete.asmx/GetCompletionList Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: There is server error, that you need to debug and test, or add log file to see error.

Comment: It was the connection string all along that was the culprit. Lesson learned, if it "the webservice" works on Localhost but not on the production server, it is most likely due to the SQL server connection string of the web service not having the appropriate credentials. Also, I had to modify the webconfig to HTTPGET and HTTPPOST.

Comment: Ok, great to know that , it is solved!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database connection was different on from the dev environment so it had to be adjusted accordingly to work from a remote server.